# root command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, github

I'm trying to setup a blog using octopress by following this [guide](http://www.bobinair.com/blog/setup-octopress-on-github-pages-gh-pages-branch). I'm stuck at the step where I do

```
root: /octopress
```

and my terminal shows

```
bash: root:: command not found
```

Comment: I think it's saying to add that line to the `_config.yml` file. I can see how that could be misinterpreted.

Comment: Yeah. Figured that out eventually. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command is meant to be added in the

```
_config.yml
```

file

```
root: /octopress
```